# Why am I getting error Error [ConfigError]: Missing region in config even if region is there?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Today suddenly I am getting this

```
error Error [ConfigError]: Missing region in config
```

which I wasn't getting yesterday. The region is there and it is the right one. Is there any other reason why I am getting this error?

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWSSECRETKEY,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWSACCESSKEY,
  region: process.env.AWSREGION,
});

// update Template parameters
var params = {
  Template: {
    TemplateName: 'Email_Registration_Verification',
    HtmlPart: `test`,
    SubjectPart: 'Verify your Email',
    TextPart: `<h1>Test</h1>`,
  },
};

var templatePromise = new AWS.SES({
  apiVersion: '2010-12-01', })
  .updateTemplate(params)
  .promise();

templatePromise
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log('Template Updated');
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err, err.stack);
  });
```

Comment: Do you have a non null value for AWSREGION in your Environment? I mean have you checked if the process.env.AWSREGION return a proper value?

Comment: Yes it does and it is the right one.